# Problems accessing tables through relationship in mysql and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using C# and the Entity Framework to access a MySQL database.
I am grabbing the results of a stored procedure, and trying to turn them into a list of objects, However whenever it comes to the part what references a table through a one to many relationship, it fails with the error

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

The code I am using is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CarHireCommon.DataObjects;

namespace CarHireServer
{
    public class DatabaseHandler
    {
        protected static DatabaseHandler instance;
        protected carhireEntities1 Entities;
        public static DatabaseHandler GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new DatabaseHandler();
            return instance;
        }

    public DatabaseHandler()
    {
        Entities = new carhireEntities1();
    }



        public List<AvailableAssets> GetAvailableAssets(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            ObjectResult<asset> res = Entities.GetAvailableAssets(startDate, endDate);

            List<AvailableAssets> list = new List<AvailableAssets>();
            foreach(var assetRes in res)
            {
                AvailableAssets asset=new AvailableAssets();
                asset.id = assetRes.id;
                asset.Comment = assetRes.comments;
                asset.Make = assetRes.make;
                asset.Model = assetRes.model;
                asset.Fuel = assetRes.fuel;
                asset.LongTerm = assetRes.longterm;
                // This is the line that errors:
                asset.Category = assetRes.category.categoryname;
                list.Add(asset);
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

I have allready told it which table the Stored Procedure returns, and the other variables access correctly.

I have also tried doing it the long way with:

```
var cat = from b in Entities.categories where b.id == assetRes.category_id select b;
asset.Category = cat.FirstOrDefault<category>().categoryname;
```

However the thing still exceptions with the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [C# Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140633/c-sharp-entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-th/7571362#7571362) which will probably help you exactly with this question.

GL!